# Conditional page layout with ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to respond to a web request with a partial view *if* the request is an Ajax request. If its not an Ajax request I would like to wrap the partial in a layout and deliver a full page.

What's the best way to do this?

Cheers, Ian.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
if(request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
    return PartialView();
} else {
    return View();
}
```

Comment: OK but actually I have multiple partials so I need a way of dynamically adding a layout. Is there a more elegant way of doing this than this... http://forums.asp.net/p/1628409/4190534.aspx ??

Comment: So you have multiple controllers and/or action methods and you want to avoid having to repeat this code in every one of them?

Comment: Yup! I suppose a filter would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two copies of the Controller method, one for HTTP GET and one for HTTP POST.  If all your AJAX uses POST, that'd handle it.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Do something
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Index()
    {
        // Do something
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Alternatively, in the [MVC3 Futures Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/07/26/using-the-features-of-asp-net-mvc-3-futures.aspx), there's an `[AjaxOnly]` tag you can use to similar effect.